# Detect if the Inno Setup installer is running when trying to Uninstall

Tags: installation, inno-setup, uninstallation

I want my Inno Setup Script to detect if my program's Setup is running before trying to Uninstall my program using `unins000.exe`.

If my program's Setup is already running when a user trying to Uninstall my program , the Uninstaller should warn user by popping a message box with a message like `Setup is running. Please install using it before uninstalling. Really want to Continue?` and with two buttons `Yes` and `No`.

- If user presses `No`, the Uninstaller (unins000.exe) must close.
- If user presses `Yes`, the uninstaller (unins000.exe) must kill the process of my program's installer (Setup.exe) and continue with Uninstalling.

How can I do this without any instability?

Thank You for your Help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to cleanly abort the installation. I would not try to kill it. Let it finish.

```pascal
[Setup]
SetupMutex=MySetupsMutexName

[Code]

function InitializeUninstall(): Boolean;
begin
  while CheckForMutexes('MySetupsMutexName') then
  begin
    MsgBox('Installer is still running', mbError, MB_OK);
  end;
end;
```